# How to rename jsGrid button class

Tags: jsgrid

I would like to rename the following button css classes set in the jsGrid prototype:

*modeOnButtonClass,
searchModeButtonClass,
insertModeButtonClass,
editButtonClass,
deleteButtonClass,
searchButtonClass,
clearFilterButtonClass,
insertButtonClass,
updateButtonClass,
cancelEditButtonClass*

Instead of doing it in the main jsgrid.js file I would like to do it in my application's js file.

jsGrid's developer suggested that I redefine the values on the jsGrid prototype before grid initialization:

```
jsGrid.Grid.prototype.headerRowClass = "my-custom-class";
```

My grids are created inside functions (like below) and I am uncertain where to insert the renaming code, and, whether it would be written differently than how the developer suggests?:

```
    function populateUsersGrid() {
        var grid = $("#users_grid").jsGrid({
            height: "auto",
            width: "100%",
            autoload: true,
            sorting: true,
            editing: true,
            selecting: false,
            noDataContent: "",
            deleteConfirm: function (item) {
                return "The User, \"" + item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name + "\" , will be removed from the Users table. Are you sure?";
            },
            controller: {
                loadData: function () {
                    var d = $.Deferred();
                    $.post("assets/php/get_users.php", {}, function (data) {
                        d.resolve(data);
                    });
                    return d.promise();
                }
                ,
                updateItem: function(item) {
                    return $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "assets/php/update_user.php",
                        data: {
                            'user_id': item.id,
                            'role_id': item.role_id
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#users_grid").jsGrid("render");
                        }
                    });
                },
                deleteItem: function(item) {
                    return $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "assets/php/delete_user.php",
                        data: {
                            'user_id': item.id
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#users_grid").jsGrid("render");
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            fields: [
                {
                    title: "Last Name",
                    name: "last_name",
                    editing: false,
                    type: "text",
                    align: "left",
                    width: "20%"
                },
                {
                    title: "First Name",
                    name: "first_name",
                    editing: false,
                    type: "text",
                    align: "left",
                    width: "20%"
                },
                {
                    title: "Email Address",
                    name: "email",
                    editing: false,
                    type: "text",
                    align: "left",
                    width: "30%"
                },
                {
                    title: "Role",
                    name: "role_name",
                    type: "text",
                    align: "left",
                    width: "20%"
                },
                { 
                    type: "control"
                }
            ]
        });
    }
```

One further wrinkle is when I inspect 'prototype' in the console the prototype values I listed above do not appear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am renaming ControlField prototypes the code needs to be:

```
jsGrid.ControlField.prototype.editButtonClass = "my-button-class";
```

I placed these lines of code at the top of my main JS file inside the `$(function () {}` code block.

CSS classes have been successfully renamed.